Notepad++ and regex: how to UPPERCASE only first letter in specific words with / find / replace
This is the given situation:
INPUT TEXT
    jjj=Johann{enter}{enter}
    uuu=08:30{tab}18:00{tab}
    vvv=08:30{up}18:45{down}08:30{left}18:45{right}08:30{tab}

OUTPUT TEXT (goal)
    jjj=Johann{Enter}{Enter}
    uuu=08:30{Tab}18:00{Tab}
    vvv=08:30{Up}18:45{Down}08:30{Left}18:45{Right}08:30{Tab}

how do I do this in Notepad++?
Find:
 {[a-z]*}

Identifies perfectly the words in curly brackets but I struggle with converting just the first character to     upper case
Substitution:
 \U$0

converts everything to     uppercase but I just want the first char to be upper case (see OUTPUT TEXT)
Could anyone please help me with that?

Try:
{([a-z])([a-z]*)}

and replace with
{\U$1\L$2}


Explanation

{...}: matches curly brackets
([a-z]): captures first letter to group 1
([a-z]*): captures subsequent letters to group 2

Then replace group 1 as upper and group 2 as lower case inside {...}

I didn't know that you were not obliged to escape the braces { and }, so good to know. I always escaped them, as they are usually used for specifying the number of occurrences of the preceding char/group. It seems that PERL wants the opening brace to be escaped.

Thank you very much, my problem is solved :-) :-) :-) Have a wonderful week!

And thank you very much also for the detailed explanation this should helpe me and hopefully others to apply it to similar cases :-)

@JohannSterzik thank you - glad i could help! Please consider accepting this as the correct solution. Have a wonderful week aswell :)
